# CoreData, PersistentStore, not retrieving any data

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data

I am using coredata to load a sqllite DB that has mainly static data. I make sure through code that the sqlite DB exists, and then do a

```
      NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
      NSEntityDescription *e = [[model entitiesByName] objectForKey:@"Item"];
      [request setEntity:e];
      NSError *error;

      // Here I never get any data
      NSArray *result = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error]; 

      if (error) {
         [NSException raise:@"Fetch failed"
                     format:@"Reason: %@", [error localizedDescription]];
      }
```

However I never get any data out of the DB!! I get no errors either, all I get is an empty array for result.
I know the sqliteDB has data in it, what could be going wrong?

Update : 
So the DB file does have values, but the behavior is inconsistent, It works fine the first time I run the app in a simulator , but If I reset Content And Settings on the simulator and then do another build, the app cannot load any data from the DB, no error or anything, it just cannot find any entries in the DB!!

Comment: Did you check your DB?
 Go to the project (app) folder inside the Simulator folder and open the DB (sqlite) file. Verify that there is data present in the DB.

Comment: Yes the DB has data, I updated my question to show some progress. Thanks

Comment: When you reset contents and settings on the simulator, the app data (and the app DB) gets deleted. Seems like your app is not able to get data from the server on the first load.

Comment: You need to have a check in place to query data from the server in case data is not present in the DB and store that data in the DB.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was intenral, I was not loading data properly.